# The series of $\sin$ and Vieta's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, pi

Suppose we have the polynomial
$$P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$$
where $a_k,z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $a_n\ne 0$. If this polynomial has roots $r_1,\ldots,r_n$, then by Vieta's formulas
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{r_k}=-\frac{a_1}{a_0}.$$

Now
$$\frac{\sin z}{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}$$
has the roots $z=\pm \pi, \pm 2\pi,\ldots$, so, upon setting $y=z^2$, the equation
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{y^k}{(2k+1)!}=0$$
has the solutions $y=\pi^2, 4\pi^2,9\pi^2,\ldots$.

**If we treat the left-hand side of this equation as a polynomial** and apply Vieta's formula we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2\pi^2}=\frac{1}{3!}\implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Question: Can we rigorously prove, **without using** $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, that the "sine series" "obeys" Vieta's formula? Does such a theorem hold more generally for other power series of complex functions? If it does, we would have an elegant proof of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Edit: As mentioned by Ethan Bolker, I'm trying to rigorously justify Euler's first method of solving the Basel problem.

Comment: That strategy was how Euler first solved the Basel problem (unrigorously, by modern standards). I'll post an answer if I can dig up a reference. (I think it's in Polya's Induction and Analogy in Mathematics). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: See Weierstrass factorization (if $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n=c\Pi (1-z/z_k)$ and $\sum 1/|z_k|$ converges then clearly $\sum  1/z_k=a_1/c$; in the $\sin$ case one uses the roots square as the function is even and the power series in $z^2$ - if the convergence is absolute like here for the roots square, the result is obvious, if the convergence is only conditional one uses some extra terms though and things are somewhat trickier but the result still holds with conditional convergence only; also the result is true for all $a_k$ with the appropriate analogues of Vieta sums for infinitely many terms

Comment: @Conrad "then clearly $\sum 1/z_k=a_1/c$" why? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Expand the product - actually one gets a minus the above; formally if $P_n$ is the finite product above of first $n$ terms one uses that $P_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on compacts (in the absolute convergence case) so in particular the $z$ coefficient of $P_n$ converges to $a_1$ (by integrating against $1/z^2$ on a circle around zero if you want formal proof of that)

Comment: @Conrad I'm familiar only with the basics of complex integration. Can you please explain why are you "integrating it against $1/z^2$ on a circle..."? You can post it as an answer and if it's good I'll accept it.

Comment: added an answer as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $g$ is an entire function of the form $g(z)=1+\sum_{n \ge 1} a_nz^n=\Pi_{k \ge 1} (1-z/z_k)$ where $\sum |1/z_k| < \infty$.

Then we claim that $a_1=-\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{1}{z_k}$ and more generally $(-1)^na_n=c_n((z_k))=\lim_{m \to \infty}c_n(z_k,m)$ where $c_m(z_k,n)$ is the $n$ Viete sum of the polynomial $P_m(z)=\Pi_{k \le m} (1-z/z_k)$ (in other words for $m \ge n$ we take $c_m(z_k,n)$ the sums of $n$ products of distinct $1/z_k, k=1,..m$ which are $(-1)^n$ times the $z^n$ coefficient of $P_m$

The proof is immediate since by hypothesis $P_m \to f$ normally on compact sets, so in particular $$\int_{|z|=1}P_m(z)z^{-n-1}dz \to \int_{|z|=1}f(z)z^{-n-1}dz,  m \to \infty$$

But by direct computation (or residues) we have that the term on the left-hand side above is $2\pi i$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ in $P_m$, hence by definition, it is $2\pi i (-1)^nc_n(z_k,m)$, while the term on the right hand side is $2\pi i a_n$

For $n=1$ we recover our claim since $c_1(z_k,m)=\sum_{k \le m}1/z_k$

Applying the above to $\Pi_{k \ge m} (1-z/k^2)=\frac{\sin \pi \sqrt z}{\pi \sqrt z}=\sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^k\pi^{2k}z^k}{(2k+1)!}=1-\pi^2z^2/6+...$ we recover the required result.

Note that inductively we can compute $\zeta(2n)$ this way since, with the notation above, $\zeta(4)=\zeta(2)^2-2c_2((1/k^2))$ and we know that $c_2=a_2=\pi^4/120$ hence $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/36-\pi^4/60=\pi^4/90$ and so on